# Point a subdomain to phpmyadmin installed on an ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost

I've been struggling a little bit with this setup. i've installed all the prerequisites for phpmydamin and itself is available at ip/phpmyadmin. Now i have a subdomain that i want to point to it. let's say i want to point data.somedomain.com to the phpmyadmin such a way that instead of ip/phpmyadmin i can access it as data.somedomain.com.I've been doing simple VirtualHost creation but i think am kind of lost in this one.
here is the `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`:

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName data.somedomain.com

  Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

 <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>
   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
        AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
 </Directory>

 # Disallow web access to directories that don't need it

 <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
 </Directory>
 <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

what i did add was the `<VirtualHost>` tag wrapper and the `ServerName` and these `Options All AllowOverride All Require all granted`

when i access the url it throws a `404` code : The requested URL / was not found on this server.

and the logs contains this entry : `File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs`
thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What happens when you try to access the URL?

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do is setup a subdomain for apache. You can do this by creating a configuration file in /etc/apache2/sites-available.

Here's mine ..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin adminn@example.local
   ServerName phpmyadmin.example.local
   DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin
   <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
   </Directory>
   LogLevel notice
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
   ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

Save that to /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf and enable the subdomain.

```
a2ensite phpmyadmin
```

And restart the apache server

```
service apache2 reload
```

Now you should be able to use phpmyadmin from phpmyadmin.example.local.

Comment: No changes DNS-side required?

Comment: if you are on local you need to redirect the domain in your `hosts` file, if you are online you need to  create an `A` Record for `phpmyadmin.yourdomain.com` and point it to your server.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need here is a CNAME with your DNS solution.  For example, if you used someone like godaddy.com, you'd add a cname data.somedomain.com on their dns management page that resolves to somedomain.com.

A cursory look through your nginx virtual host, you may want to start with a minimal config first that simply points requests for data.somedomain.com to your /usr/share/phpmyadmin.  I'd also suggest locking down phpmyadmin with htaccess (nothing worse than having your db hacked.)

Comment: as is right now the domain before the setting of the vitualhost attemps resolves to the correct ip and it shows "it works!!". Will add the htaccess thanks

Comment: what does a `# whois data.somedomain.com` spit out?

Answer (score 0):

There error message you mentioned `File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs` is definitely a sign of the parameter `DocumentRoot` not being properly specified for the virtualhost. Make sure you point it to the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is still setup under the path `/phpmyadmin`, you should find that http://data.example.com/phpmyadmin/ works. You can either change the `Alias` directive (and other references to `/phpmyadmin`) to `/` to present it under the root:

```
Alias / /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Or you can redirect `/` to `/phpmyadmin`:

```
RewriteRule   ^/$  /phpmyadmin/  [R]
```

Comment: You can disable access to /phpmyadmin with command sudo a2disconf phpmyadmin